# Use string formatting to hide username and password in JSON payload sent in request header

Tags: python, json, string, request, formatting

I have a function that has parameters with username and password. I want to use f strings or any sort of string formatting so that I don't have to hard code the username and password in the code and rather substitute those arguments passed to the function as well as it violates security requirements.

the payload has to be in the format as shown below unless there is another possibility to send the payload in JSON. As this needs to be send via JSON only I guess. If I try to remove the backslash it errors on me for indentation.

How can i leverage string formatting to hide username and password so that I can provide these information during runtime.

```
import requests
import sys, pprint, json
from getpass import getpass
from multiprocessing import Pool
import yaml
from functools import partial

http_header = {}
url_dict = {}

def getCookie(username, password, ip_addr):

    url = "https://"+ip_addr+"/api/aaaLogin.json"

    # payload = " {\r\n\"aaaUser\":"\
    #           " {\r\n\"attributes\":"\
    #           " {\r\n\"name\": \"admin\",\r\n" \
    #           "  \"pwd\":\"Admin_1234!\"\r\n" \
    #           " }\r\n " \
    #           " }\r\n }\r\n"

    payload = {
        # 'aaaUser':'',
        # 'attributes':'',
        'name': username,
        'pwd': password,
    }
    json_payload = json.dumps(payload)

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    }

    try:

        req = requests.request("POST", url=url, data=json_payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
    except:
        print('Failed to obtain auth cookie: %s' % (e))
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        cookie=req.headers['Set-Cookie']
        # print(cookie)
        return cookie

def genericGetRequest(ip_addr, cookie, apiurl, verb):
    url = 'https://'+ip_addr+apiurl
    http_header["Cookie"]=cookie
    http_header["Host"]=ip_addr
    try:
        req = requests.request(verb, url=url, headers=http_header, verify=False)
    except:
        print("There is a problem with the {} request!".format(verb))
    else:
        return(req)

def getResults(username, password, ip):
    cookie=getCookie(username, password, ip)
    if cookie:
        print("User is logged in. Auth-cookie is  %s\n" % cookie)
        vlan_list = []
        trunk_vlans_dict = {}
        for i in range(1, 49):
            apiurl = f"/api/mo/sys/intf/phys-[eth1/{i}]/.json"
            generic = genericGetRequest(ip, cookie, apiurl, 'GET')
            generic = generic.json()
            imdata = generic['imdata']
            vlan = imdata[0]['l1PhysIf']['attributes']
            trunk_vlans_dict[f"eth1/{i}"] = vlan['trunkVlans']
        vlan_list.append(trunk_vlans_dict)
        print(vlan_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    print("Enter password")
    password = getpass()


    if password:
        deviceListFile = 'nexus_list.yaml'
        with open(deviceListFile) as f:
            deviceList = yaml.load(f)

        num_threads = 5
        print("Retreiving Configuration: ")
        pool = Pool(num_threads)
        partial_getResults = partial(getResults, username, password)
        pool.map(partial_getResults, deviceList)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    else:
        print("Passwords do not match. Exiting...")
```

After using json dumps I am getting another error as shown below. BTW I have posted entire code for clarity sake.

```
ssh://vrxxx@werssefsf:22/sdfsdfsdfsdf/Python_Dev/Test1/pyVENV/bin/python -u /NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/Test1/nxos_test5.py
Enter username: admin
admin
Enter password
Password: Admin_1234!

/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/Test1/nxos_test5.py:82: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  deviceList = yaml.load(f)
Retreiving Configuration: 
/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/Test1/pyVENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/Test1/nxos_test5.py", line 58, in getResults
    cookie=getCookie(username, password, ip)
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/Test1/nxos_test5.py", line 42, in getCookie
    cookie=req.headers['Set-Cookie']
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/Test1/pyVENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/structures.py", line 52, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'set-cookie'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/Test1/nxos_test5.py", line 88, in <module>
    pool.map(partial_getResults, deviceList)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
KeyError: 'set-cookie'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: Your question won't get answered as you'd need to create a new question as it's unrelated to your original one.  3 things I would change/try, 1) being pedantic I would change url = f"https://{ip_addr}/api/aaaLogin.json" as it's easier to read, 2) I would test the value of cookie to ensure I have it, do you? 3) I would try req = requests.request(verb, url=url, headers=http_header, cookies=cookie, verify=False) and remove http_header["Cookie"]=cookie. Requests creates the CookieJars for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without a minimal example.  It's also not clear what aaaUser, attributes and ip_addr is used for but I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
    import json
    
    def getCookie(username, password, ip_addr):
        payload = {
            'name': username,
            'pwd': password
        }
        return json.dumps(payload)
    
    print(getCookie(username='admin', password='Admin_1234', ip_addr="127.0.0.0"))
    # {"name": "admin", "pwd": "Admin_1234"}
```

There is unlikely a need for all the new lines and string formatting, you just need to pass the Python dictionary through the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) dumps method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Johnny. Your suggestion worked. I just have to use aaaUser and attributes in a nested dict format as shown below.

```
payload = {
    'aaaUser': {
    'attributes': {
    'name': username,
    'pwd': password,
}}}
json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
```